# Apache - Serve all files in subdirectories

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, alias, subdirectory

My server acts as a personal file share. I would like to set up a folder, _misc, which contains random files. Further, I need extra folders inside _misc to act as categories for files. What I've been trying to do these last couple nights is configure it in such a way that all files within _misc and it's subfolders can be accessed from the domain root.

```
Examples:
www.example.com/_misc/chatlog.txt
www.example.com/_misc/food/burgers.jpg
www.example.com/_misc/sounds/soundclip.mp3

Can all be accessed as:
www.example.com/chatlog.txt
www.example.com/burgers.jpg
www.example.com/soundclip.mp3
```

As well, I need the rest of the file system to be served as normal. I have other files in the root that I will keep, as well as a few Wordpress sites and auth folders and just general server related stuff.

I tried to use alias, which could almost work. I don't mind configuring each folder inside of _misc, since there's <12. However I don't think alias allows multiple calls to "/" and it also redirects the actual "/" to "_misc".

mod_rewrite could almost work if it would allow me to use regex on the directory side.

I am a programmer, my last resort is using an external program for mod_rewrite which can scan _misc and return the actual path for the requested file. I'm not sure how well this is going to work out though.

Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, untested, mod_rewrite rewriterules. Please note that this is potentially taxing on the server, because for every request that is made to the server, a lot of subrequests are done to check if files exist on the server. As a result, the server is likely unable to serve as many requests/minute as it otherwise could. The environment variable trick is there to prevent even more requests to be made.

If you can, use this in httpd.conf instead of .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ - [E=notfound:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:notfound} =1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_misc/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /_misc/$1 [L,E=!notfound]

RewriteCond %{ENV:notfound} =1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_misc/food/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /_misc/food/$1 [L,E=!notfound]

RewriteCond %{ENV:notfound} =1
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/_misc/sounds/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /_misc/sounds/$1 [L,E=!notfound]
```

I am unsure if `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` contains a trailing slash or not. You might need to write it as `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}_misc` instead.

Comment: Holy senpai code, sweet! I never thought rewrite was this powerful. I had only known about the basic RewriteRule command. So I implemented your script this morning and learned what it all did. On my particular setup, regardless of documentroot having a trailing slash, the slash in the code is optional. Weird.

I had to adjust the top line to include root and add a slash to the regex as: ^/(...

Comment: You were also right about the throughput, testing from the local network before it was about 100k/minute. With this code, it's about 25k/minute even if the file exists in root already. However, the response times are faster, and also with mass requests the server cpu usage drops from 30% to <10%. The code is much appreciated.

Comment: That's the difference between directorycontext (.htaccess, <directory> blocks) and virtualhost context (<virtualhost> blocks).